# Seeming contradiction in inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, vectors, free-body-diagram

[image]

According to the above picture,let's an object falls from rest. After any time $t$,we analyze the distance traveled in two ways:

*Way $1$*

Just like we do in projectile motion,we divide the motion of the object in $y$ axis and $x$ axis. In that case, according to the figure, $u_y=0$ and hence $h'=u_yt+\frac{1}{2}gt^2=\frac{1}{2}gt^2$.

*Way $2$*

We use the ordinary calculations. First of all,gravity along the inclined plane will be $g'=g\cos \theta$. Also initial velocity in inclined plane $u=0$. Hence $s=ut+\frac{1}{2}g't^2=\frac{1}{2}g\cos \theta t^2$. And from normal trigonometry,$\frac{h'}{s}=\cos \theta$ and hence $h'=s\cos \theta=\frac{1}{2}g\cos^2 \theta t^2$.

In *way $1$* we just divided the problem into $x$ and $y$ axis just like we do in projectile motion and deduced $h'=\frac{1}{2}gt^2$. But again,we did everything normally in *way $2$* and got $h'=\frac{1}{2}g\cos^2 \theta t^2$. I am guessing *way $1$* is wrong since we did not assume anything in *way $2$*. So,what is wrong with assuming motion in seperate axes in that method? I will be very grateful if someone provides a kind explanation.

Answer (score 10):

Way 1 is incorrect because the $y$-component of acceleration is not $g$, but rather $g$ minus the component of the normal force which points in the $y$-direction:
$$g - g \; \sin^2 (\theta).$$

You can see will simplify to $g \; \cos^2(\theta)$, which is consistent with way 2.

Answer (score 5):

In the first method you are assuming that the vertical acceleration is $g$ downwards but it's not.  It is true for a projectile because the force of gravity is the only force acting but in the case of something sliding down an inclined plane there is another vertical force, the vertical component of the normal force, so the vertical acceleration is less that $g$.